# How to invoke a method of one of several static classes chosen at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, static-methods

I'm using several classes to deliver services, e.g. there is a class for FTP, another for HTTP, both implement the same methods, but customized to the protocol:

```
public static class FtpProvider { public static string GetString () { return "1"; } }
public static class HttpProvider { public static string GetString () { return "2"; } }
```

I need a simple service selector, to switch the static class providing the services. I use a Type variable to hold the current provider e.g.

```
Type _type = (condition) ? typeof (FtpProvider) : typeof (HttpProvider);
```

I then call the method of the selected class using reflection. The whole code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main () {
        Type _type = (new Random ().NextDouble () > .5) ? typeof (FtpProvider) : typeof (HttpProvider);
        string _methodName = nameof (FtpProvider.GetString);
        MethodInfo _method = _type.GetMethod (
            _methodName,
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        object _result = _method.Invoke (null, null);
        Console.WriteLine (_result.ToString ()); Console.ReadKey ();
    }
}
public static class FtpProvider { public static string GetString () { return "1"; } }
public static class HttpProvider { public static string GetString () { return "2"; } }
```

This does works but it's really a ugly piece of code for switching static types at runtime, considering it's only to replace a call like `currentProvider.GetString ()`. So I would like to know:

- If there is a better design for switching static class providers.
- If this way is acceptable, can the code be simplified?

Update:

1. I tried the singleton pattern with an interface, but static method can't implement the interface, and the instance creation seemed to me too much as the services are stateless. I also tried the abstract base class, but again the constructor must be in each derived class.
2. If the static method is a problem, please explain the reason (I understand it's not object oriented indeed).

Comment: Why must these classes be `static`?  You could use an interface to contain your `GetString` method, and have both classes implement the same interface. Then some other code can choose which class type to instance and use, but it gets passed around as the interface type.  You could then use the Singleton pattern if you wanted to only ever have one instance of each provider type.

Answer (score 1):

Static types do not support inheritance or Liskov substitution. They're not meant to. That is why your code is so messy-- what you're doing is very strange. You ought to implement these providers as regular instanced classes with a common interface, if you want it to be easy.

That being said, if you are absolutely stuck using static classes, one way to make this far easier is to use a provider map.

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,Func<string>>
{
    { "HTTP", HttpProvider.GetString },
    { "FTP", FtpProvider.GetString }
};
```

Once you have the map, the rest is easy:

```
var protocol = (new Random().NextDouble() > .5) ? "FTP" : "HTTP";
var result = map[protocol]();
Console.WriteLine(result); 
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, I'll need a map per service, maybe more than 20, but it's a good restart, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using the Singleton pattern instead of `static` classes, and an interface to achieve what you want.  No reflection required.  You can access the 'provider' from the static `CurrentProvider` property (or else change that access around how you like).

Hopefully your provider classes overlap enough that there is a common interface you want to use with them.  Then the rest of your app doesn't have to know what the actual type of provider is; they just interact with the interface.

Notice I've made the default constructor for the singletons `private`, so the only way to get an instance of this class is by calling the static Instance property.  Hence, they behave similarly to a static class.  (You might also consider marking these `sealed`, if you really don't want people to construct them outside of the static Instance property.)

You can still switch providers by toggling the Condition variable.  I suggest not having it be a `bool`, but perhaps an `enum`, though you can modify how the Condition works later.

```
using System;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Condition = new Random().NextDouble() > .5;
            Console.WriteLine(CurrentProvider.GetString()); Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool Condition;
        static IProvider CurrentProvider => Condition ? FtpProvider.Instance as IProvider : HttpProvider.Instance as IProvider;
    }

    // interface allows for multiple provider types
    public interface IProvider
    {
        string GetString();
    }
    public class FtpProvider : IProvider
    {
        // use Lazy<T> to implement Singleton pattern
        private static readonly Lazy<FtpProvider> lazy = new Lazy<FtpProvider>(() => new FtpProvider());
        public static FtpProvider Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return lazy.Value;
            }
        }
        // don't allow normal construction of this class
        // force everyone to use Instance
        private FtpProvider() { }

        public string GetString() => "1"; 
    }
    public class HttpProvider : IProvider
    {
        // use Lazy<T> to implement Singleton pattern
        private static readonly Lazy<HttpProvider> lazy = new Lazy<HttpProvider>(() => new HttpProvider());
        public static HttpProvider Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return lazy.Value;
            }
        }
        // don't allow normal construction of this class
        // force everyone to use Instance
        private HttpProvider() { }

        public string GetString() => "2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this and found two light problems: The instance creation and the impossibility to implement the interface using static methods. I must say none is a no-go.

Comment: If the instance creation is a problem, perhaps you need to update your question with more information about _why_ you must have everything be static.  Is it because you have no control over the static classes, say because they're in a compiled library?